# Creating a menu in Cocos2d-Android

Tags: cocos2d-android, ccmenuitem

I am a beginner in Android Development and have been working on a game in cocos2d-android and need to implement a menu screen.  I have looked on google and can only find information in regard to cocos2d for iPhone.  Would anyone have any advice/ideas as to how I could add a menu, or even better know of any tutorials or books that could help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can create menu in cocos2d with use of CCMenu and CCMenuItemLabel here i am sharing you an example from which i made menu screen for option so it will helpful to you here the method which shows you to use of CCMenu and CCMenuItemLabel so try it all the best.

```
     private CCNode addOtherOptions(String strName, int xpos, int ypos, String action) {
            CCNode ccStartNode = CCNode.node();
            ccStartNode.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(xpos, ypos));
            ccStartNode.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));

            CCMenuItemLabel startGame = CCMenuItemLabel.item(strName, this, action);
            startGame.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
            startGame.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
            startGame.setColor(ccColor3B.ccc3(139, 69, 19));
            startGame.setScale(0.5f);

            CCMenu menu2 = CCMenu.menu(startGame);
            menu2.alignItemsVertically(-10f);
            menu2.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(-20, 0));
            menu2.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0, 0));
            // addChild(menu2);

            ccStartNode.addChild(menu2);

            return ccStartNode;
        }
```